# search form css class loaded twice and affecting placement after ajaxcomplete function

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, animation, search

I have a search form that loads content from the server and places it in a div. That works well and fine. But after I add an ajaxComplete function to add a class that animates the results it has unexpected outcome.

The search box and result container both shift to the left of the page and back to original position in a glitchy matter after the first letter is input. It wont do that afterwards but the results loading up seem to go from opacity 0 to 1 to 0 again and back to 1.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");

  if (inputVal.length) {
    $.get("backend-search.php", {
      term: inputVal
    }).done(function(data) {
      resultDropdown.html(data);
    });
  } else {
    resultDropdown.empty();
  }

});

//-----------------------tablefade in

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('#resulttbl').addClass('fadein');
});
```

```css
.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  height: 9%;
  padding: 3% 2% 3% 2%;
  border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.result {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 %5;
}

.search-box input[type="text"],
.result {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#resulttbl {
  //---------this is the table loaded thru ajax
  border-spacing: 40px;
}

input[type="text"]::placeholder {
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
  }
}

.fadein {
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Please search by Name, State, or Specialty..." />
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a working example to reproduce your problem, please? We can't  do the ajax call to your `backend-search.php` so we can't see your problem and therefore it's hard to help you. At least for me. Sorry :'(

Comment: @ReSedano sorry about that!! ive updated my post:))

Comment: the situation is still the same, Sally. We can't connect to your database: you have to do a static example so that we can see your problem. I did this jsfiddle to try to replicate your error, but it seems work well. Please, check it and change it: try to replicate your error by yourself and after post your work so we can help you. :) https://jsfiddle.net/g9ycepta/1/

Comment: ...or upload your work somewhere and give us the link :P

Comment: You can try to put `$('#resulttbl').addClass('fadein');` after `resultDropdown.html(data);` and remove `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {...`. But it is only an hypothesis, without seeing the problem :'(

Comment: @Resedano thank you!! i tried adding the class after the resultDropdown var but it had the same effect:// However in your jsfiddle it seemed to have the same "blinking" (opacity from 0 to 1 back to 0 and stopping at 1) problem that i did, i dont know if you had any luck with that. It looks like the class is added and removed right after. maybe thats whats causing the conflict. I had no luck recreating the error without sql nn im hosting it locally. I dont know if you can tell but im quite new to building things from the ground up:P Sorry about that and thanks again!!:))

Comment: @Resedano sooooooooooooooo i figured out the "glitchy" movement bug.........i wrote the margin for my result class as "0 5% 0 %5"........./.\ im such a dunce, i was up all night trying to figure it out:P youre js fiddle code pointed out the error that brackets juss told me it was a okay -.- you are my savior haha one more to go:P hopefully i have good news about the blinking glitch later. thanks buddy:))

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeee!! I'm really happy for you!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Some minor modifications on your provided snippet could solve this problem.

**Javascript:**
Check [jQuery Promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) functionality and take a look on the last example. The same concept is used below to add the class `fadein` after `resultDropdown.html()` method has finished generating the HTML from the ajax response.

**CSS:**
changed

```
.result {
  display: block;
  ...
```

to

```
.result {
  display: none;
  ...
```

and added

```
.fadein {  
  ... 
  display: block !important;
}
```

```js
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");

  if (inputVal.length) {
    $.get("backend-search.php", {
      term: inputVal
    }).done(function(data) {
           $.when( resultDropdown.html(data); ).done(function() {
               $('#resulttbl').addClass('fadein');
           });          
    });
  } else {
    resultDropdown.empty();
  }

});

//-----------------------tablefade in
```

```css
.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  height: 9%;
  padding: 3% 2% 3% 2%;
  border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.result {
  display: none;
  height: 20%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 %5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#resulttbl {
  //---------this is the table loaded thru ajax
  border-spacing: 40px;
}

input[type="text"]::placeholder {
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
  }
}

.fadein {
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Please search by Name, State, or Specialty..." />
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

> A more solid example could be provided if you could simply post the code for `resultDropdown.html()` and `resultDropdown.empty()` methods and some example `data` returned from server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help:)) sorry for the late reply i had to deal with my day job -.-

So there was two issues: one because im an idiot and the other because well yeah im stupid. First the margins on the "result" class were set to %5 and that made it do some weird things. Also having the "result" as a class nested in a "search-box" class made the animation play twice. I was following a tutorial and i guess i hadn't thought about it... it also didnt help that while i was trying to debug i wasnt clearing my cache because i didnt know that was an important part 0.o

Thank you all again:)) hopefully ill be able to make some live examples with php when i can buy a lil piece of the internet